# Android : Separate resources for 'androidTest''

Tags: android, android-resources, android-testing

I want to use separate set of Resources while running test, so I set up a file named 'configs.xml' in

> 'src/androidTest/res/values'

and added this to gradle

> sourceSets {
>           androidTest {
>               resources.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/res']        }
>           }  }

But when I try to fetch the resource using the below line

> String s1 = getInstrumentation().getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.test_config);

I get this below error

> 01-08 18:06:13.814  16761-16774/com.example.hellodroid I/TestRunner﹕ android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f070008
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1382)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:1476)

Can somebody point out where I am going Wrong ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` file, this should work:

```
sourceSets {
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}
```

This allows, I believe, `tests/java`, `tests/res` folders etc.